# How can i get a moving RPS graph for a subset of requests in Application Insights?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I'm trying to create a load test simulation for a specific set of URL's.

To do that, i need to understand usage of these requests in my production app.

So what i'm looking for is the 'average' RPS of my specific API URL's over time. This will allow me to create a min/max RPS to target.

I can't see how to do this with Application Insights.

Can someone provide guidance? Maybe i need to export IIS logs and do manually?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a query like this in analytics:

```
requests
| where timestamp > datetime(2019-04-16T21:22:00Z)
| where timestamp < datetime(2019-04-16T21:32:00Z)
| summarize sum(itemCount) by bin(timestamp, 1s) 
| render timechart
```

(replace with actual time)